# sql oracle count lower/upper case

Tags: sql, oracle

I have usernames with upper and lower case: 
Example:

- kelly, KellY, KELLY, kELLy, max, james, James, Carl

how to count this values in order to have the amount (count) 
in this case should be: 4
and not 8

```
SELECT 
    username,
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    usertable
GROUP BY 
   username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LOWER` to convert all the names to the same case, and then count `DISTINCT` values:

```
 COUNT(DISTINCT LOWER(username))
```